# Taking Partial Derivatives of Composite Functions

Tags: calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I've got a question about taking the partial derivative of a function defined by the sum of two composite functions from a past exam I'm doing and kind of stuck, wondering if anyone can help me with it.

$f(x,y)=g(\frac{x}{y})+g(\frac{y}{x})$

where $g$ is differentiable for  $xy\neq0$. Evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and deduce that $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$.

I think what I've done so far is correct:

$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{y}\frac{\partial g(\frac{x}{y})}{\partial x} - \frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial g(\frac{y}{x})}{\partial x}-\frac{x}{y}\frac{\partial g(\frac{x}{y})}{\partial y}+\frac{y}{x}\frac{\partial g(\frac{y}{x})}{\partial y}$

But I'm not too sure on how to simplify this further down to 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what I'd thought but the simplification just doesn't seem to be working out for me and I'm a little confused. And yeah I've just fixed that up - thanks for pointing it out, multivariable stuff is still pretty new for me, habits and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain this in a slightly more general setting.  Note that $g$ is actually a function of one variable.  Although we have both $x$ and $y$ in the input expression for $g$ in both terms on the RHS, the point is that $g$ only has one input position, as opposed to, for example, $f$, which has two input positions.

So we can say $u(x,y) = x/y$ and $v(x,y) = y/x$.  Then the equation becomes
$$ f(x,y) = g(u(x,y)) + g(v(x,y))$$

Now if we take $\partial/\partial x$ of both sides:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(u(x,y)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(v(x,y))$$

So what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(u(x,y))$?  Well, remember that $g$ is just a function of one variable, so we'll get
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(u(x,y)) = g'(u(x,y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y)$$
from the chain rule.
Similarly,
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(v(x,y)) = g'(v(x,y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} v(x,y)$$
So all together, we have
\begin{align*}
  f(x,y) &= g(u(x,y)) + g(v(x,y))\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(u(x,y)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(v(x,y))\\[0.3cm]
    &= g'(u(x,y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y) + g'(v(x,y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} v(x,y)\\[0.3cm]
    &= g'\left(\frac xy \right) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac xy \right) + g'\left(\frac yx \right) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac yx\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= g'\left(\frac xy \right) \cdot \left(\frac 1y \right) + g'\left(\frac yx \right) \cdot \left( -\frac y{x^2}\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac 1y g'\left(\frac xy \right) - \frac y{x^2} g'\left(\frac yx \right)
\end{align*}

Addendum:

Following a similar process, we get
$$
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -\frac x{y^2} g'\left(\frac xy \right) + \frac 1x g'\left(\frac yx \right),
$$
so then
$$
  x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac xy g'\left(\frac xy \right) - \frac yx g'\left(\frac yx \right)
$$
and
$$
  y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -\frac xy g'\left(\frac xy \right) + \frac yx g'\left(\frac yx \right).
$$

Showing $\displaystyle x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ from here is straightforward, but it is not the same thing as showing $\displaystyle \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$.  For one thing it's ambiguous which $g$ is being referred to ($g(x/y)$ or $g(y/x)$) but it actually doesn't matter which one, because
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g\left(\frac xy \right) = \frac 1y g'\left( \frac xy\right) \ne -\frac x{y^2} g'\left( \frac xy\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g\left(\frac xy \right)
$$
and
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g\left(\frac yx \right) = -\frac y{x^2} g'\left( \frac yx\right) \ne \frac 1x g'\left( \frac yx\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g\left(\frac yx \right).
$$
There may be specific values of $x$ and $y$ for which the two "$\ne$" above become
"$=$" but the point is that $\partial g/\partial x$ and $\partial g/\partial y$ are not equal to each other in general.  But $\displaystyle x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is equal to zero in general (as long as $xy \ne 0$).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I'd managed to muddle myself up to this point but lacked proper understanding. So now I think since g is really only a function of only one variable the partial of g wrt x and y are the same, so then my equation in my (now edited) question becomes 0, right? @tilper

Comment: @jamesmbcn, $\partial g/ \partial x$ and $\partial g/ \partial y$ aren't the same.  To show that $x \partial f/\partial x + y \partial f/\partial y = 0$ you can use a symmetry argument or, probably a better idea, just evaluate $\partial f/\partial y$ directly and then show the desired result.

Comment: right - I gave the second option a go and got the result in my original question above. Would this then simplify to 0 directly or am I missing a further step?

Comment: @jamesmbcn, it's basically a direct result.

Comment: wouldn't that then be implying that partial of g wrt x is the same as the partial of g wrt y? Apologies, but +x/y is being multiplied by partial of g wrt x and -x/y is being multiplied by partial of g wrt y, so how would they cancel out?

Comment: @jamesmbcn, see the edits I made to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$f(x,y)=g(\frac{x}{y})+g(\frac{y}{x})$$

$$=g_1(x,y)+g_2(x,y)$$.

with

$$dg_1=\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial y}dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{y}g'(\frac{x}{y})dx-\frac{x}{y^2}g'(\frac{x}{y})dy$$

by the same,  we get

$$dg_2=\frac{1}{x}g'(\frac{y}{x})dy-\frac{y}{x^2}g'(\frac{y}{x})dx$$

thus

$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=x\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x}=$$

$$=\frac{x}{y}g'(\frac{x}{y})-\frac{y}{x}g'(\frac{y}{x})$$
$$y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-\frac{x}{y}g'(\frac{x}{y})+\frac{y}{x}g'(\frac{y}{x}).$$

we check that

$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!